# load data from model into checkboxlist

Tags: php, yii

I need to create check box list content for Example departments and user can check multiple box.

With drowpdownlist I can load value like this :

model :

```
public function getsection(){
    return array (
        CHtml::listData(Csection::model()->findAll(),'section_id','ar_name'),
    ); 
}
```

view :

```
echo CHtml::activedropDownList(
  $models,
  'section_id', 
  $models->getsection(),
  array(
    'size'=>'4',
    'prompt'=>'أSelect Sections ',
    'multiple' => 'multiple',
  )
);
```

So how can I do that with checkboxlist, also how to process values in controller, is it like drowpdownlist ?

Comment: Not work and return Array to string conversion error ?!

Comment: oops didn't see that you were returning array(), just remove that, i.e return listdata directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Chtml::activeCheckBoxList

```
echo Chtml::activeCheckBoxList($models, 'section_id', $models->getsection());
```